# Silverstripe Blog Tags add class for current tag filter

Tags: tags, widget, blogs, silverstripe

Sorry I'm kinda new to Silverstripe.

Is there a way to add a active/current class to the BlogTagsWidget.ss list items?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the BlogController is the current controller when `BlogTagsWidget.ss` is rendered, you may be able to use this method directly to check it in the template, e.g.

```
<% loop $Tags %>
    <% if $CurrentTag && $CurrentTag.ID == $ID %>
        Current
    <% else %>
        Not current
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

If it's not available then you may need to add some extra code to provide the current tag boolean in `BlogTagsWidget::getTags()`.